# problem with .wax format

Tags: 10.04, video-player

I installed Ubuntu 10.4 onto a pc for an elderly woman. It was supposed to solve the problems she was having with windows, ie: she would constantly remove things, or try to fix problems herself. So I figured that Linux would solve those issues. However, what I didn't take into account was that she watches " http://www.shepherdschapel.com/broadband.htm " and when using Ubuntu, I can't seem to find a media player to make the files work. I am out of ideas. I tried kplayer, and it worked (sort of). The file that is downloaded from the site when you click the windows media player site one link is, .wax format. Which is an instruction file for windows media player. Is there anything I can do to make these videos work?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any files in `.wax` format. The formats on offer from the site are `.wmv` and `.rm` as far as I can see. The videos play fine within `firefox` if you have `vlc` and the browser plugin installed as that can handle wmv streams. So install `firefox` and `vlc` and then see the note below about installing the plugin:

**NOTE**: The vlc plugin for 12.04 is `browser-plugin-vlc`, **but** as you say you are running 10.04 you will need to install `mozilla-plugin-vlc` instead.

After installing `vlc` and the appropriate plugin for your Ubuntu version check firefox > preferences to see if wmv files are associated properly; the screenshot below shows how they now should look (although it might be slightly different and state mozilla plugin in 10.04). If the windows media files are not associated with the plugin simply choose the plugin from the list and associate them.

**Now** when you click on any video or audio .wmv streaming link from the site the media will start playing within the browser immediately; try single clicking [this link](http://www.shepherdschapel.com/media/sc/9_12_2012_hi_vid.wmv) or the most recent video link on the site when you read this answer.

[image]